# make a movie with axes from images matlab

Tags: image, matlab, movie, axes

i have a folder with jpg images and i want to convert them into a movie but i also want to have axes on the movie (images dont have axes).my images are grayscale.i ve done something  but it is incorrect. the command movie(F,1); shows the movie but the axes are not fix on the movie .also the avi that i save shows only the movie (motion of the images) without the axes. this is my code:

```
vidObj = VideoWriter('sample.avi');
open(vidObj);
for num_frame=1:40
     %find filename of the image
     filename = sprintf('%s_%d.jpg','new_image/sample_image',num_frame);
     cmap = colormap(gray);
     res = grs2rgb(filename,cmap);%convert image from grayscale to rgb
     F(num_frame)=im2frame(res);
 end
 imshow('new_image/sample_image_1.jpg');%show the first image
 set(gca,'FontSize',14);
 xlabel('Lateral distance [mm]');
 ylabel('Axial distance [mm]');
 xlim([-50 50]);
 ylim([20 105]);
 axis([-50 50 20 105]);
 axis ('on');
 movie(F,1);
 writeVideo(vidObj,F);
 close(vidObj);
```

what is the mistake??

Comment: Have you tried [getFrame](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html?nocookie=true)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the axis setup you are doing is only used in MATLAB and is not saved with the video. To save the axis setup, you can use `getframe` to create a new frame of the current plot. I suggest the following:

```
vidObj = VideoWriter('sample.avi');
open(vidObj);

for num_frame=40:-1:1
    % load image
    filename = sprintf('%s_%d.jpg','new_image/sample_image',num_frame);
    cmap = colormap(gray);
    res = grs2rgb(filename,cmap);

    % create plot
    imshow(res);
    set(gca,'FontSize',14);
    xlabel('Lateral distance [mm]');
    ylabel('Axial distance [mm]');
    xlim([-50 50]);
    ylim([20 105]);
    axis([-50 50 20 105]);
    axis ('on');

    % save current plot as movie frame
    F(num_frame) = getframe(gcf);
end

writeVideo(vidObj,F);
close(vidObj);
```

Note the `for num_frame=40:-1:1`: This is to preallocate `F` at the first iteration, which is better for speed (MATLAB doesn't need to extend the variable at each iteration)